# How to use log4j to output to a single log file from a multi-module project?

Tags: maven, log4j

Is there a way to have all log4j output write to a single log file when I have a multi-module project in Maven? Also, could I configure a single properties file for for all modules?

Comment: i think you know to use log4j and file appenders. try to put the log4j.xml file in your src/main/resource folder with all your appenders. if you have a war packaging pom use it in the same module. the main use of the modules is to use them separately if you want to use them separately i suggest you to use it in each modules with same file name for the appender

Comment: As long as you have only one log4j configuration file on the classpath at runtime, the application will use its configuration.  If your configuration forces everything into a single file, it will go into a single file.